# Can @media query be used in a pop up window?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, popup

A media query, for example, @media (max-width: 500px), measures the size of the main browser window. I am wondering if the query can measure a pop up window width, so that I can set different layouts in the window when it is resized.

I am currently using Kendo Window, if anyone knows specific answer related to this widget is greatly appreciated, but any knowledge to pop up window in general is satisfied.

Comment: No you can't. `@media` is (mainly) related to the width of the viewport. With Kendo UI, I guess you could - in JS - listen to any [event](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/events) occuring on pop-in ("Window") and then measuring its width (I write _any_ event because there are strange ones like double clicking on title maximizes Window... No control for that but it still happens)

Comment: * `@media` can be related to a lot of things ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)) but when it comes to viewport and browser window dimensions, there's nothing related to the content of the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS media queries work for the whole viewport dimensions only.

With regard to the Kendo UI Window, you can use its [`resize`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-resize) event and make layout readjustments programmatically. For example, you can use a couple of alternative CSS classes for the Window's [`element`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/wrapper-element) and control the layout similar to media queries.